# Why Java does not allow using `_` (single underscore) as parameter name in lambdas?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

When you try to use `_` as a parameter name in a Java 8 lambda, you get a `Use of '_' as a lambda parameter name is not allowed` error message.

[image]

Two underscores is ok though:

[image]

Any reason on why one single underscore is not allowed?

Comment: Because we have bigger plans for underscore in the future -- but it takes several versions to complete such a repurposing.  Took two full versions (warning in 8, error in 9) to remove it from the space of identifiers.

Comment: Are those plans published somewhere? what's the goal actually?